# Regular expression for price - Android

Tags: java, android, regex, regular-language

I have a `string` like bellow :

```
dfdfm;lg 2500$ jshfsnefsfz5405€mnvkjdf64rfmkd554668¢ odsfrknegj 885486¥ dsflkef 588525dollar
```

I am getting bellow values with this `[\\d,]+\\s*\\$|[\\d,]+\\s*€|[\\d,]+\\s*¥|[\\d,]+\\s*¢|[\\d,]+\\s*dollar` :

> 2500$
>   5405€
>   554668¢
>   885486¥
>   588525dollar

**Problem :**  But I don't need to these `$ € ¢ ¥ dollar` . How I can delete these in top regex ?

Here is my method :

```
private String getPrice(String caption) {
    String pricePattern = "[\\d,]+\\s*\\$|[\\d,]+\\s*€|[\\d,]+\\s*¥|[\\d,]+\\s*¢|[\\d,]+\\s*dollar|[\\d,]+\\s*Euro";
    List<String> lstPrice = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern rPrice = Pattern.compile(pricePattern);
    Matcher mPrice = rPrice.matcher(caption);
    while (mPrice.find()) {
        lstPrice.add(mPrice.group());
    }
    if (lstPrice.size() > 0) {
        return lstPrice.get(0);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: use groups  `([\\d,]+)` and your regex can be optimized as well

Comment: Perhaps I have a string like this : dsfsdfd58ssdf8745$ . and then get me 58 and 8745 .I need just to price .

Comment: I need just prices .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to return all prices, make sure your `getPrice` method returns `List<String>` and adjust the regex to match the prices but capture the numbers only:

```
private List<String> getPrice(String caption) {
    String pricePattern = "(?i)(\\d[\\d,]*)\\s*(?:[$€¥¢]|dollar|Euro)";
    List<String> lstPrice = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern rPrice = Pattern.compile(pricePattern);
    Matcher mPrice = rPrice.matcher(caption);
    while (mPrice.find()) {
        lstPrice.add(mPrice.group(1));
    }
    return lstPrice;
}
```

See the [Java demo online](http://ideone.com/rUMz8M).

```
String s = "dfdfm;lg 2500$ jshfsnefsfz5405€mnvkjdf64rfmkd554668¢ odsfrknegj 885486¥ dsflkef 588525dollar";
System.out.println(getPrice(s));
```

returns

```
[2500, 5405, 554668, 885486, 588525]
```

**Pattern details**:

- `(?i)` - a case insensitive modifier (embedded flag option)
- `(\\d[\\d,]*)` - Group 1 capturing a digit and then 0+ digits or `,`
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:[$€¥¢]|dollar|Euro)` - either `$`, `€`, `¥`, `¢`, `dollar` or `euro` (case insensitive search is enabled via `(?i)`)

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew . Your response is true . Thanks a lot .

Comment: Accept this answer .

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **replaceAll**

> Replaces every subsequence of the input sequence that matches the
>   pattern with the given replacement string.

```
 String pricePattern="2500$ 5405€ 554668¢ 885486¥ 588525dollar";  
 pricePattern= pricePattern.replaceAll("[^\\d+]", " "); //2500 5405 554668 885486 588525
```

Check **[Java Demo](http://ideone.com/Un9zYZ)**

Comment: You should specify that you're talking about a post-treatment. I believe TO wanted to modify his regex so it does both at once.

Comment: @ IntelliJ Amiya . Your response is true . Thanks a lot .

Comment: This method will also keep other digits (like years, hours, etc.) that are not part of a price. This method will work in some edge cases when there are only prices,  and no other digits in the input string.

Comment: But for Wiktor Stribiżew is more complete. Don't worry for accept answer Wiktor Stribiżew. ok ?

Comment: @JoJoRoid No problem .Choose better one

Comment: Thanks for you guide . ;)